# -lrandomProcesses not found

Tags: 14.04, bash, compiling

I am attempting to install a piece of software and when it is installing (technically compiling) I recieve an error called

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrandomProcesses
```

I have looked on the internet and could not find a specific package to install this onto.

Would anyone have an idea on how I can correct the issue?

Comment: What is the software? it doesn't sound like a system library - possibly a prerequisite that needs to be built first?

Comment: It is openFoam again

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile randomProcesses explicitly

```
 cd src/randomProcesses
 ./Allwmake
```

I had issues with multiple versions of FFTW library on my computer, but following actions fixed them

1. In *ThirdParty-v1606+/makeFFTW* change **“fftwPACKAGE=${fftw_version:-fftw-system}”** to **“fftwPACKAGE=${fftw_version:-fftw-3.3.4}”**
2. Run ./ThirdParty-v1606+/makeFFTW
3. Proceed with compilation of *randomProcesses*